# non-PID which where all prime ideals are maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

What are examples of non-PID rings for which all prime ideal are maximal? I am not so sure about the non-examples of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain). Is $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such an example?

Comment: Is it possible to classify such commutative rings ?

Comment: any Dedekind domain which it is not PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, but the ideal $(2)$ is prime and not maximal. The ring $k[x]/(x^2)$ is an example of a ring with exactly one prime ideal, but is not a domain, so not a PID. In $k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ you again have exactly one prime ideal, and it is not principal.